# Showing that two surfaces are not isometric/locally isometric

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I am trying to solve an exercise which asks to show that two surfaces are not isometric and additionally that they are not locally isometric. The two surfaces presented are graphs. I know that if two surfaces have the same First Fundamental Form then they are locally isometric but how can I show that two surfaces are NOT isometric and also not locally isometric? Are there some equivalent conditions?

Comment: Hint: Use curvature.

Comment: Could you elaborate at all? Do you mean to compute the Gaussian curvatures of both surfaces, note that they are different, and conclude that the surfaces are not locally isometric? Does this also show that they are not globally isometric? I ask because in the exercise, the question of being locally isometric and isometric are split into two different parts. Thank you.

Comment: Yes: Gaussian curvature is a function, so you may want to compute it. If $K_1(p)\ne K_2(q)$ then there is no local isometry $S_1\to S_2$ sending $p$ to $q$. If functions $K_1, K_2$ have, say, different minima/maxima, and so on, then surfaces cannot be globally isometric.

Comment: Preparing for math 380 are we? ;)

Comment: What is math 380?